# SQLServer Regexp empty string matching

Tags: sql-server, regex

using the RegExp capabilities of SQLServer, I need to find all strings that are not starting with the letter 'M', but `[^M]%` seems to work so that it's searching strings that don't start with 'M', but the string still need's to have at least one character, so this pattern will not return empty strings!!

So is there `[^M]%` pattern that checks ZERO or ONE character?

p.s. Using `NOT LIKE` is not an option in my case, nor is any kind of modifications to the where clause except the regexp pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a condition `OR MyField = ''`. You are using SQL Server 2012, right? By looking at the help page I don't see any "or" condition for the regexps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't this actually find empty strings? The OP wanted to make sure it was at least one character long.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Quoting from OP: `so this pattern will not return empty strings!!`

Comment: I guess after reading it again about 30 times I can see that interpretation. 99% the battle here is understanding the question anymore!

Comment: Ok, so this one seems impossible :(

Answer (score 1):

One way to make `[^M]%` match `''` is to just append a character that is not `M` to the input;

```
where Fld + '?' like '[^M]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

For pure regex you would have to use CLR user defined functions.

With regex support you may search for those of the form `\b|[^M].*` which allows **a blank or a non-M character followed by zero or more characters**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx may help you.